# Node-Powershell Azure function app will not read commands

Tags: node.js, azure, powershell, azure-functions

I am running Powershell commands in a node.js script to connect to Microsoft-Exchange with a certificate thumbprint.I am using the node-powershell npm package. All works as expected locally. When deploying to Azure the Powershell commands dont seem to run. Has anyone else had success deploying a similar script?

```
   let ps = new shell({
      executionPolicy: "Bypass",
      noProfile: true
   });
```

```
  ps.addCommand('Connect-ExchangeOnline -CertificateThumbPrint "thumbprintString" -AppId "APP_ID"
-Organization "example.onmicrosoft.com"');
            ps.invoke()
               .then((output) => {
                  console.log(output);
                  resolve();
               })
               .catch((err) => {
                  console.log(err);
                  reject(err);
               });
```

Comment: When you say "deploying to Azure" are you talking about an Azure Functions? Or an Azure IaaS VM? Where/what are you deploying this script to?

Comment: @Mike Azure function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by async of the function, so you can see the result was print in local but can't see it on azure portal.

Please notice the logs in local, we can find the `output` which print in logs comes after the log `Executed 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=70bbb908-fddf-4f4d-8115-aa1523e04361, Duration=48ms)`. So the `output` was print when the function had been completed. If you deploy it to azure, it will just print the logs to `Executed 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=70bbb908-fddf-4f4d-8115-aa1523e04361, Duration=48ms)` and will not continue to print the `output`.

To solve this problem, you can modify your code from:

```
ps.addCommand('Connect-ExchangeOnline -CertificateThumbPrint "thumbprintString" -AppId "APP_ID"
-Organization "example.onmicrosoft.com"');
            ps.invoke()
               .then((output) => {
                  console.log(output);
                  resolve();
               })
               .catch((err) => {
                  console.log(err);
                  reject(err);
               });
```

to

```
ps.addCommand('Connect-ExchangeOnline -CertificateThumbPrint "thumbprintString" -AppId "APP_ID"
-Organization "example.onmicrosoft.com"');
try {
    const result = await ps.invoke();
    context.log(result);
} catch (error) {
 
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!!